# Runing processing Sketch with vs code/terminal extension in ubuntu throws error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, processing

I want to run a processing sketch and not use the processing IDE (I'd like to use vs code and its extension, but also running it from the command line would be ok)  under ubuntu 20.04.
I installed the `processing-java` under `/opt/processing-4.0.1/processing-java`.

Then I want to run this example sketch which I grabbed from the website:

```
/**
 * Array 2D. 
 * 
 * Demonstrates the syntax for creating a two-dimensional (2D) array.
 * Values in a 2D array are accessed through two index values.  
 * 2D arrays are useful for storing images. In this example, each dot 
 * is colored in relation to its distance from the center of the image. 
 */

float[][] distances;
float maxDistance;
int spacer;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  maxDistance = dist(width/2, height/2, width, height);
  distances = new float[width][height];
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      float distance = dist(width/2, height/2, x, y);
      distances[x][y] = distance/maxDistance * 255;
    }
  }
  spacer = 10;
  strokeWeight(6);
  noLoop();  // Run once and stop
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  // This embedded loop skips over values in the arrays based on
  // the spacer variable, so there are more values in the array
  // than are drawn here. Change the value of the spacer variable
  // to change the density of the points
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y += spacer) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += spacer) {
      stroke(distances[x][y]);
      point(x + spacer/2, y + spacer/2);
    }
  }
}
```

For that I use that command:

```
/opt/processing-4.0.1/processing-java --sketch=<name_of_folter_with_sketch> --output=~/Desktop --force --run
```

Yet I receive this error (I receive the same error when trying to run the sketch from the vs-code extension):

```
/opt/processing-4.0.1/processing-java --sketch=2dPerlinNoise --output=~/Desktop   --build
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at processing.app.Sketch.getMainName(Sketch.java:1699)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.preprocess(JavaBuild.java:144)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.build(JavaBuild.java:110)
    at processing.mode.java.Commander.<init>(Commander.java:233)
    at processing.mode.java.Commander.main(Commander.java:417)
```

In the Processing-IDE it runs with no problems...
Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Any ide

Comment: Looks like it's expecting a parameter which you're not giving it. You're supplying no (non-positional) parameters - those are all options/directives. The IDE might well get one or more parameters 'automatically' Perhaps [this](https://www.dsfcode.com/using-processing-via-the-command-line/) might help...

Comment: Please provide more details about the error.

Comment: I have the same error, maybe it has something to do with the new Java update, i did yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it helped to rename my project to a name without:

- spaces
- any special characters
- numbers

Be sure to change the name of the directory, as it has to be same as the `.pde` file.